# limiting a field value in firebase security rules inside of a nested object?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a nested object in my doc that has the key as an id. The value of this key is 1 in the initial phase, however I want to gain control over the incoming value in security rules.

I have no reference for the key, so there is no way I can know it (if there is such method).

Is there any way to be able to target the key of this objects in security rules in a manner that will allow me lock it to (<= 12) max ?

All keys inside the object can have the same rules so if there is a general method to make this check it would be sufficient.

```js
//{ dataObj: { [/*some id as key*/]: 1 } };

const payload = { dataObj: { CTubWp9QW4UbtO9Xk5Eg : 1 } }

updateDoc(doc(db, `data-uses/${userId}/generalData/${subUserId}`), payload).catch((error) => console.log(error));


match /data-uses/{userId}/generalData/{subUserId} {
  allow create: if
    // Rules 
    request.resource.data is map &&
    // Creating 
    request.resource.data.dataObj[key /*for demostration*/] == 1;
  // Updating 
  allow update: if
    request.resource.data is map &&
    request.resource.data.dataObj[key/*for demostration*/] == resource.data.dataObj[key /*for demostration*/] + 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show fully formed (but still minimal) security rules, and the document that exists in the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did edit hope it will make more sense now,  I am not sure if there is a method the could limit the data value of an incoming object that has keys under the same condition in this case not bigger than 12, it would have been more easier if I had the id but it is a generated id.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the problem. If you don't know the key name, how do you expect to restrict the values on it? It might help if you show a concrete example of the document you're tryinh to modify, and the type of write operation that you're tryin to allow/deny.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the point is i will never know the key since it is automatically generated, but the question is whether I can control the key values even if I don't have access to the objects keys by using some method that could limit object's values to something specific.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my goal is to limit the creation of nested data inside the super collection, the idea is you cannot have more than 2 super collections and that was handled by other (not mentioned counter ) so i did this nested counter for the sub collection so I can limit the number of docs created inside each of the 2 allowed sub collections.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding the problem. If you're asking whether you can iterate across all fields in security rules, the answer is "no" - there are no loops whatsoever as that wouldn't scale. If that's not the question, I recommend updating the question to clarify - and then hopefully somebody else understands it enough to help with an answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not a loop but something similar to .keys() method available on a map but covers the values similar to  Object.values() in js where you could. if there is not such a thing I will delete.

Comment: Deleting a question is not needed, especially not as we've been trying to get to an answer here. `.keys()` does exist on the `data()` object and (afaik) also on any map field under it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the img it might make more sense now , of what I am trying to achieve, only 2 sub collections can be created on doc level and only 12 docs inside each collection can be created.

Comment: There's no direct way to limit the number of docs that can be created in a collection. The only way to do that (without Cloud Functions) is to keep a counter of the number of documents created, increment/decrement that from the client, and then enforce both the increment/decrement and the limit in security rules.